# swap the content of 2 shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

When swapping the content of two `shared_ptr`s, only the contents are swapped. When there is a `shared_ptr` created from the other one before the swap, I am surprised that the content of the new `shared_ptr` copy remains the same.

Here is an example:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<int> foo (new int(10));
std::shared_ptr<int> bar (new int(20));

auto abc = foo;
std::swap (foo, bar);
std::cout << "foo: " << *foo << '\n';
std::cout << "bar: " << *bar << '\n';
std::cout << "abc: " << *abc << '\n';
```

It prints:

```
foo: 20
bar: 10
abc: 10
```

Why is `abc` not 20 in this case? Given that it's a copy of `foo`.

Comment: "When swapping the content of two shared pointer, only the contents are swapped." ... typo?

Comment: what output did you expect?

Comment: `abc` is a copy of `foo` as it was before the swap. Swaping an object doesn't also swap previous copies of it. You may be confusing your code (which swaps what each pointer points to) with `std::swap(*foo, *bar);` (which swaps the pointed values).

Comment: after all, a shared pointer is just a pointer (well, ok its more, but nevertheless it models a pointer), and swapping two pointers does not affect other poitners to the same objects.

Comment: "abc is a copy of foo right now" is very different from "abc is and always will be a copy of foo". Assignment does the first thing. In order to do the second thing, you need magic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shared_ptr` is just a pointer to data.  You are not swapping the data itself, you are swapping the pointers.

Lets look at it step-by-step:

> ```cpp
> std::shared_ptr<int> foo (new int(10));
> std::shared_ptr<int> bar (new int(20));
> ```

After these statements, you have two pointers to two separate allocated `int`s:

```
[ foo ] ---> [10]
[ bar ] ---> [20]
```

> ```cpp
> auto abc = foo;
> ```

This statement then creates `abc` to point at the same allocated `int` that `foo` is pointing at.  So, before the swap, you now have:

```
[ foo ] -+-> [10]
         |
[ abc ] -+

[ bar ] ---> [20]
```

> ```cpp
> std::swap (foo, bar);
> ```

Then, you are swapping the pointers that `foo` and `bar` are holding, but you are leaving the pointer in `abc` alone.  So, after the swap, you now have:

```
    +---------------+
    |               |
[ foo ]  +-> [10]   |
         |          |
[ abc ] -+          |
         |          |
[ bar ] -+   [20] <-+
```

That is why `*foo` prints 20, `*bar` prints 10, and `*abc` prints 10.

Answer (score 2):

> When swapping the content of two shared_ptrs,....

Thats not what your code does. `std::swap(foo,bar)` swaps the pointers. It does not swap the pointees. If you want to swap the contents you need to swap the contents: `std::swap(*foo,*bar)`.

---

The fact that it is smart pointers it not actually relevant for your code. Also the dynamic allocation does not change much, so we can use a simpler example for illustration:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

int* a_ptr = &a;
int* b_ptr = &b;

int* c_ptr = a_ptr;
```

Until now, you have two pointers `a_ptr` and `b_ptr` pointing to `a` and `b`, respectively. `c_ptr` is a copy of `a_ptr` and points to `a` as well.

```
std::swap (a_ptr,b_ptr);
```

After swapping `a_ptr` and `b_ptr` you now have `a_ptr` pointing to `b` and `b_ptr` pointing to `a`. The third pointer, `c_ptr` is not affected by that. It still points to `a`. Also `a` and `b` are not modified.

```
std::cout << "foo: " << *a_ptr << '\n';
std::cout << "bar: " << *b_ptr << '\n';
std::cout << "abc: " << *c_ptr << '\n';
```

Output will be:

```
20
10
10
```

Just as in your code.